# How to turn on google location service at runtime like Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

How to turn on google location service at runtime like Google Maps ?

Using request permission or another way?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to turn on GPS location.

```
private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

You can use whatever message you want to use.

Edit:

To turn GPS on directly use this:-

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
                LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                        .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

                builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

                PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                        final Status status = result.getStatus();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                try {
                                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                    // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                    status.startResolutionForResult(
                                            MainActivity.this, 101);
                                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                    // Ignore the error.
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but is there any way else to turn on it directly in this activity that don't need to change to setting activity